# Error while connecting sql server with visual studio 2022 in Mac Os not in window

Tags: asp.net-core

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

appsetting.json connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=Bulky;User=sa;Password=Admin@123;"
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it just adding `TrustServerCertificate=true;` to my connection string

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**You can try below methods.**

#### Method 1

You can add `tcp:` in your connection string.

> "DefaultConnection":"Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;Database=Bulky;User=sa;Password=Admin@123;"

#### Method 2

Add `Polling=True`

#### Method 3

Open 1433 port in MacOS.